# Filling a dataframe section by section without a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have Dataframe like so:

```
  sync 
0    1
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    0
```

the sync column switches between 0 and 1.
I need to create a new column, that is filled with an item of a list, based on the Delta of the sync column.

For example the list with the values to fill is `[17, 8, 0]`

Then the result Dataframe should look like this:

```
  sync   res
0    1   NaN
1    1    17
2    0     8
3    1     0
4    0    17
```

So basically everytime the sync column has a Delta != 0, the next value of the list should be appended. The list should be repeated if its shorter than the rows of the dataframe.
This is not so hard to achieve with the `.iterrows()` or `.itertuples()` function. The Problem is that the dataframe usually has 6 Million rows and it takes a while.

I've read iterating over rows of a dataframe is not good practice, because it's slow.
So i need a solution without a loop but i cant think of any function that i can use with `df.apply()` that would solve the problem.

Here is my current solution:
I created a dataframe with only these rows, where sync has a Delta != 0 and iterated over every row of that dataframe but it still takes quite a while (ca. 500s).

```
mylist = [17, 4, 9, 3, 76, 4]
listindex = 0

# calculate the difference
diff = data[data["time"] >= starttime].diff()

# get all the rows where the Delta is != 0
edges = diff[diff["sync"] != 0]

old_index = 0

# initiate res column
data['res'] = 0

for index, edge in edges.iterrows():
    if old_index:
        # fill rows from "oldindex" to "index+1" of "res" column with value of "mylist"
        data.at[old_index:index+1, "sync"] = mylist[listindex]
        # increment index if its not the end of the list
        if 0 <= listindex < len(mylist)-1:
            listindex += 1
        else:
            listindex = 0
    # save current index for next iteration
    old_index = index
```

Comment: Your sync column of the sample is different from the sync from the expected output.

Comment: You code references a `grip` column that does not exist in sample data...

Comment: can sync be null? what happend in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution with `np.title`:

```
# data 
df = pd.DataFrame({'sync':[1,1,0,1,0]})
lst = [17,8,0]

# initialization
df['res'] = np.nan

# fill
non_zeros = ~df['sync'].diff(-1).eq(0)
df.loc[non_zeros, 'res'] = np.tile(lst, non_zeros.sum())[:non_zeros.sum()]
```

Output:

```
   sync   res
0     1   NaN
1     1  17.0
2     0   8.0
3     1   0.0
4     0  17.0
```

**Note**: If the other columns do not relate to the output in anyway, consider removing them out of the sample data (as in my sample).